# Masking raster based on vector shapefile

Tags: r, scale, masking

For this work Data are obtained from:-
For Raster:-*https://download.hermes.com.np/land-cover-map-of-nepal-2010/*.
For Vector :-*https://cellapp.co/download-nepals-new-map-vector-image/*.
Rupandehi District was then selected and exported as a part of this work (named here as RupandehiLocalPlace).

Then, I clipped a raster file based on vector shapefile.
The code I used as shown:-

```
library(sf)
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
setwd("C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/EM")
LCN<-raster("np_lc_2010_v2f.tif")
RLU<-shapefile("RupandehiLocalPlace")
proj4string(RLU)
proj4string(LCN)
plot(LCN)
plot(RLU)
proj4string(LCN)<-CRS("+proj=utm +zone=44 +datum=WGS84 +units=m 
+no_defs")
raster::projection(LCN)
LCN<-crop(LCN,RLU)
plot(LCN,main="Forest Area in 2019")
plot(LCN,
main="Forest Area in 2019",
axes=TRUE)
plot(RLU,add= TRUE)
```

The result obtained is shown below:-
[image]

But, I don't have an idea of masking data.

Could someone let me know how to mask these data (raster based on vector)?

Also, I couldn't see spatial scale in either of direction.

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First mask, then crop. This is using terra package (although I think you shared the wrong raster). Also you can select the district and reproject easily:

```
library(terra)

r <- rast('~/Downloads/Land%20Cover%20Map%20of%20Nepal%202010/np_lc_2010_v2f.tif')
v <- vect('~/Downloads/Local Unit/local_unit.shp')

v <- v[v$DISTRICT == "RUPANDEHI",]

v <- project(v,r)

plot(mask(crop(r,v),v))
plot(v, add = T)
```

[image]